# Dataframe.shape tuple index out of range

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

```
print "Boston housing dataset has {} data points with {} variables each.".format(df.shape)
```

gives an error saying "tuple index out of range"

while

```
print "Boston housing dataset has {} data points with {} variables each.".format(*data.shape)
```

outputs the dimension of the dataframe correctly. Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: `df.shape` is tuple so, it causes error but using `*df.shape` is unpacking tuple and mapping to corresponding `{}` bracket in the `.format()`. You can see the difference with:
`print(df.shape, sep='\n')` will print tuple whereas, `print(*df.shape, sep='\n')` will unpack each element and print in new line.

Comment: Thanks for your concise and precise response. Now, I clearly understood it.

Comment: np, further example on unpacking can be found in https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists and http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pip2/Tuples/TupleAssignmentwithunpacking.html